# check if my teamspeak server is online

Tags: php

I want to add a teamspeak server status checker on my website, to check if it is online or offline

is there a way to do it in php, or jquery, javascript or in some other way?

I tried this, in php, but it does not work...

```
<?php 
function check_ts($ip, $tcp, $udp, $timeout=1) { //Function for the Check 
$fp = @fsockopen($ip, $tcp, $errno, $errstr, $timeout); 
if (!$fp) { 
  $stat = false; 
} else { 
  if (fgets($fp) == "[TS]\r\n") { 
 fputs($fp, "SEL $udp\r\n"); 
 if (fgets($fp) == "OK\r\n") { 
   $stat = true; 
 } else { 
   $stat = false; 
 } 
  } else { 
 $stat = false; 
  } 
  if (is_resource($fp)) 
 @fclose($fp); 
  return $stat; 
} 
} 

if (check_ts("my_WAN_ip", 10011, 9987)) { //Change IP, Query-Port and TS-Port 
 echo "<FONT COLOR=#00DD00><B>ONLINE</B></FONT>"; 
} else { 
 echo "<FONT COLOR=#DD0000><B>OFFLINE</B></FONT>"; 
} 
?>
```

I've also tried different ports found in **[this post](https://support.teamspeakusa.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/44/16/which-ports-does-the-teamspeak-3-server-use)**, but it does not work

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Framework/Class that does exactly what you need. It's called 'TS3 PHP Framework' (see: https://www.planetteamspeak.com/)

**Example:**

```
//Load Framework
require_once("libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php");

try {
   //Connect
   $ts3 = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://query_user:query_pass@host:10011/?server_port=9987");

   //Server Status
   echo "Server Status: online";
}
catch(Exception $e) {
   //Errors (No connection)
   echo "Server Status: offline";
}
```

You can find more examples in the official documentation: http://docs.planetteamspeak.com/ts3/php/framework/

Comment: I downloaded the framework, and uploaded on my server, then I've created a php page (check-teamspeak.php) with your code, but when I browse that page, I see only webserver errors (orange apache errors)... [SEE THE IMAGE](http://oi61.tinypic.com/amp1eu.jpg)

Comment: Your server doesn't allow `require_once()` try `include()` instead, and check if the path is correct.

Comment: ok, but now It shows always: "Server Status Offline"... The teamspeak server now is online, I'm talking with my friend in it now, but it shows always offline....

Comment: Can you add `echo $e->getMessage();` to the catch block, and check if an error is being outputted?

Comment: "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host unknown."       I've tried to login with standard username and passw, or serveradmin & password, or leave it a syour code (query_user:query_pass).... What have I to write in them?

Comment: Can you post your `::factory` string? (Without the password of course)

Comment: $ts3 = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://mike1:MYPASSW@host:10011/?server_port=9987");

Comment: You need to replace `host` with the servers hostname/ip.

Comment: Impossible establish the connection. Persistent refuse by destination computer.